# Why double stack capacity instead of just increasing it by fixed amount?

Tags: arrays, stack

I'm using using an array implementation of a stack, if the stack is full instead of throwing error I am doubling the array size, copying over the elements, changing stack reference and adding the new element to the stack. (I'm following a book to teach my self this stuff).

What I don't fully understand is why should I double it, why not increase it by a fixed amount, why not just increase it by 3 times.

I assume it has something to do with the time complexity or something?

A explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Question title does not make sense. You may want to rephrase it.

Comment: FYI 2 is the factor used by the standard implementation of a Stack in java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doubling has just become the standard for generic implementations of things like array lists ("dynamically" sized arrays that really just do what you're doing in the background) and really most dynamically sized data types that are backed by arrays.  If you knew your scenario and had the time and willpower to write a custom stack/array list implementation you could certainly write a more optimal solution.

If you knew in your software that items would be added incredibly infrequently after the initial array was built, you could initialise it with a specific size then only increase it by the size of what was being added to preserve memory.

On the other hand if you knew the list would be expanded very frequently, you might chose to increase the list size by 3 times or more when it runs out of space.

For a generic implementation that's part of a common library, your implementation specifics and requirements aren't known so doubling is just a happy medium.

Answer (score 3):

In theory, you indeed arrive at different time complexities. If you increase by a constant size, you divide the number of re-allocations (and thus O(n) copies) by a constant, but you still get O(n) time complexity for appending. If you double them, you get a better time complexity for appending (armortized O(1) IIRC), and as you at most consume twice as much memory as needed, you still got the same space complexity.

In practice, it's less severe, but nevertheless viable. Copies are expensive, while a bit of memory usually doesn't hurt. It's a tradeoff, but you'd have to be quite low on memory to choose another strategy. Often, you don't know beforehand (or can't let the stack know due to API limits) how much space you'll actually need. For instance, if you build a 1024 element stack starting with one element, you get down to (I may be off by one) 10 re-allocations, from 1024/K -- assuming K=3, that would be roughly 34 times as many re-allocations, only to save a bit of memory.

The same holds for any other factor. 2 is nice because you never end up with non-integer sizes and it's still quite small, limiting the wasted space to 50%. Specific use cases may be better-served by other factors, but usually the ROI is too small to justify re-implementing and optimizing what's already available in some library.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with a fixed amount is choosing that fixed amount - if you (say) choose 100 items as your fixed amount, that makes sense if your stack is currently ~100 items in size. However, if your stack is already 10,000 items in size, it's *likely* to grow to 11,000 items. You don't want to do 10 reallocations / moves to grow the size of your stack by 10%.

As for 2x versus 3x, that's pretty arbitrary - nothing wrong with choosing 3x; which is "better" will depend on your exact use case and how you define "better".

Answer (score 0):

Scaling by 2x is easy, and will ensure that on average items get copied no more than twice [an expansion will copy half the items for the first time, a quarter for the second, an eighth for the third, etc.]  If things instead grew by a fixed amount, then when e.g. the twentieth expansion was performed, half the items will be copied for the tenth time.

Growing by a factor of more than 2x will increase the average "permanent" slack space; growing by a smaller factor will increase the amount of storage that is allocated and abandoned.  Depending upon the relative perceived "costs" of permanent and abandoned allocations, the optimal growth factor may be larger or smaller, but *growth factors which are anywhere close to optimum will generally not perform too much worse than would optimum growth factors*.  Regardless of what the optimum growth factor would be, a growth factor of 2x will be close enough to yield decent performance.